# MYSQL PHP JSON returning all images for each product

Tags: php, mysql, json

i need this JSON output

```
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
        "strImageName ": {
                          "image1":"image_for_1.jpg",
                          "image2":"image_for_2.jpg",
                          "image3":"image_for_3.jpg"
                         }
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "ProductName": "bbbbbb",
        "strImageName ": {
                          "image1":"image_for_1.jpg",
                          "image2":"image_for_2.jpg"

                         }
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "ProductName": "ccccccc",
        "strImageName ": {
                          "image1":"image_for_1.jpg"


                         }
    },
```

**-------------------------- MYSQL -----------------------**

The table structure is very similar:

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
    ProductID int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProductName varchar(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intProductID)
);

 CREATE TABLE Products_images (
    ImageID int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProductID int(11) NULL,
    strImageName varchar(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intImageID)
);
```

Populate the tables with:

```
INSERT INTO Products(ProductName)
VALUES
('Product #1'), ('Product #2'), ('Product #3');

INSERT INTO tblProductImages (ProductID, strImageName) 
VALUES
(1, 'image_for_1.jpg'),
(1, 'image_for_2.jpg'),
(1, 'image_for_3.jpg'), 
(2, 'image_for_1.jpg'), 
(2, 'image_for_2.jpg'),
(3, 'image_for_1.jpg');
```

I want to do a SELECT that returns all 3 products, with images all images off each product. Similar to:

```
ProductID  ProductName  strImageName
1          Product #1   image_for_1.jpg
2          Product #1   image_for_2.jpg
3          Product #1   image_for_3.jpg
4          Product #2   image_for_1.jpg
5          Product #2   image_for_2.jpg
6          Product #3   image_for_1.jpg
```

My simple solution :

```
"SELECT 
                p.ProductID ,
                p.ProductName ,
                i.strImageName 
              FROM 
                 Products p
              LEFT JOIN tblProductImages i
                 ON p.ID = i.ProductID 
              ";
```

**----------------------PHP----------------------**

```
$num = $result->rowCount();
if($num > 0) {
    // Post array
    $product_arr = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row);
      //echo $Designation. "\r\n";

     $product_item= array(
        'ID' =>$ID,
        'ProductName' => $ProductName,
        'strImageName' => $strImageName
      );  

      // Push to "data"
      array_push($product_arr, $product_item);


    }
    // Turn to JSON & output
    echo json_encode($posts_arr);
  } else {
    // No Products found
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'No Products Found')
    );
  }
```

**---------------------- Problem ---------------------**

When i do This the output is

```
{"ID": "1",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_1.jpg"} ,
{"ID": "1",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_2.jpg"} ,
{"ID": "1",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_3.jpg"} ,


{"ID": "2",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_1.jpg"} ,
{"ID": "2",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_2.jpg"} ,


{"ID": "3",
  "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
  "strImageName ":"image_for_1.jpg"}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use GROUP BY ProductId,ProductName in select query.

Comment: You talk about PHP and converting some model to JSON but there is no PHP in your provided codes. Please show you PHP code as well.

Comment: If you expect mysql to provide ready to use json then you should look at json aggregate functions. But it should be easy to do it in php. Please extend your post with either php code or json specific SQL so people could help you.

Comment: @Ali Khalili,@Maxim Sagaydachny please check the edit code (PHP)

Comment: @Kawaljeet Singh moor explain please -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should somehow group your images by product ID. So, for example, you can do something like this: use a key value array to see if a product is already extracted or not, if no, save the product with its first image into our array, else: only insert the image into the array of images related to that product.

```
if (isset($product_arr[$ID])) {
     //if the product is already inserted into our array, just insert another image to the extracted images of that product
     $product_arr[$ID]['strImageName'] [] = $strImageName;
} else {
     //if we see the product for the first time, insert the product to our array
     $product_arr[$ID] = array(
        'ID' => $ID,
        'ProductName' => $ProductName,
        'strImageName' => array($strImageName)
      );
}

//then
echo json_encode(array_values($product_arr));
```

Comment: thanks bro @Ali Khalili , the result now is like  this ["1" :{
        "ID": "1",
        "ProductName": "aaaaaaa",
        "strImageName ": {
                          "image1":"image_for_1.jpg",
                          "image2":"image_for_2.jpg",
                          "image3":"image_for_3.jpg"
                         }
    } not like format in output question

Comment: did you use `json_encode(array_values($product_arr))` or `json_encode($product_arr)`?

Comment: Thank you @Ali Khalili yes when i used `array_values($product_arr)`  give me true output **+1000 likes** you saved my day